# Як вживати слово "наступний"

Tags: вибір-слова

У [дослідженнях](http://dspace.nbuv.gov.ua/handle/123456789/122950) мовознавця І.Заліпської є думка про те, що слово *наступний*, вжите в контексті "за мить про наступне", "а правда полягає в наступному" це слово є лексичною калькою з російської мови, а правильним було би замінити його словом *такий*.
Водночас, в Російсько-українському словнику 1930р. (О. Ізюмов) воно наводиться як відповідник російському "следующий" з зауваженням:

> 2) (перед перечислением или об’яснением) таки́й, отаки́й, ось таки́й, ось що. Разговор шел о следующем – розмо́ва була́ ось про що. Договор заключен на следующих условиях – до́говір скла́дено на таки́х умо́вах.

В Російсько-українському народному словнику таке зауваження відсутнє. То чи не стало таке вживання слова "наступний" унормованим?

Answer (score 1):

Ось яке пояснення дає [Онлайн Корректор](http://onlinecorrector.com.ua/%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D1%83-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%96%D0%BA%D1%83/):

> Якщо після конструкції з прикметником наступний іде перелік, замініть
>   на: такий.

**Не рекомендовано**:

> Рекомендовано наступні заходи: заощадження електроенергії, скорочення
>   робочого часу, скорочення адміністративних витрат.

**Рекомендовано**:

> Рекомендовано такі заходи: заощадження електроенергії, скорочення
>   робочого часу, скорочення адміністративних витрат.

Але:

> У наступні 20-25 років Україні треба провести багато реформ.

Врахуйте, тут пише "не рекомендовано", а не "помилка", тобто, гадаю, що у певних випадках це не вважатиметься грубою помилкою.

А ось [уроки державної мови, де бачимо таку ж інформацію:](http://slovopedia.org.ua/30/53409/26359.html)

> Наступний – який з’являється слідом за чимось; найближчий у часі чи
>   просторі. Залежно від контексту це слово має кілька значень:
>   “дальший”, “подальший”, “другий”. Якщо йдеться про предмети або
>   конкретні явища, здебільшого вживають прикметник наступний: наступний
>   урок, наступного дня (тижня), наступна зупинка. Коли ж мовиться про
>   абстрактні явища, що відбувалися чи відбуватимуться після якогось
>   часу, події, частіше вдаються до прикметників дальший, подальший:
>   дальше життя, подальша доля, подальша робота. Ненормативними є вислови
>   на слідуючий день, слідуюче питання, слідуюча зупинка і т. д.
>   Дієприкметник слідуючий, що входить до них, неможливий навіть
>   теоретично, бо в українській мові немає дієслів, од яких можна було б
>   його утворити. **Втім, замість сталося наступне ліпше сказати сталося
>   ось що. Перед переліком або поясненням доречне слово такий. Не
>   наступні факти, а такі факти, не з наступних спеціальностей, а з таких
>   спеціальностей, заявляти не наступне, а таке.**